# Oracle SQL - Joining rows that don't exist?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Take these two example tables:

```
Table A
Name   FirstOrLast
Jeremy First
Smith  Last
Mark   First
David  First


Table B
Name
Jeremy
Smith
Mark
David
Jones
Jack
```

I would like the output to be this: Output only first names, but if Table A doesn't record if it's a first or last name, output it anyway. The correct output would be:

```
Jeremy
Mark
David
Jones
Jack
```

I've tried accomplishing this with an outer join, like so:

```
select
  B.Name
from
  A, B
where
  A.name = B.name(+) and
  A.FirstOrLast = 'First';
```

but no luck. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you perform a left outer join and there is no record in `A`, `a.firstOrLast` will be null. While you're at it, you might as well switch to the standard syntax for joins:

```
select
    B.Name
from
    B
left outer join A on A.name = B.name
where
A.firstOrLast is null or A.firstOrLast = 'First';
```

However, the old syntax should also work:

```
select
    B.Name
from
    A, B
where
    A.name = B.name(+) and
    (A.firstOrLast is null or A.firstOrLast = 'First');
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Two questions: Why is the "standard" syntax better (my company uses the (+) syntax, but I am very new to sql, so I am open to changing my style). Two, can you explain what A.name = B.name(+) accomplishes here?

Comment: @Jeremy The old syntax works only on Oracle; the new syntax works on most modern RDBMSs. Before SQL got standartized, RDBMS vendors defined their own syntax for this: for example, Sybase used `A.name *= B.name`. The outer join marker `(+)` means "do not remove the row on the left even if the row on the right is not present".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT  B.Name
FROM    B LEFT JOIN A ON B.Name = A.Name
WHERE   A.FirstOrLast = 'First' OR A.Name IS NULL;
```

Comment: This gives the same output as mine (with or without my outer join). Also A.name at the end should be A.FirstOrLast but I made the same mistake in my question.

Comment: @Jeremy. That answer is exactly the same like the answer you accepted, why do say it's not working?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm sure that "or A.Name is NULL" wasn't there, but it looks like it hasn't been edited. I'm so confused. Well, I'll upvote anyway since this is indeed a perfect answer.

Comment: @Jeremy. Nope, it was here all the time... **:)**

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.name
from b
union
select a.namfe
from a
where a.firstOrLast = 'First'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name
FROM B
MINUS
SELECT Name
FROM A
WHERE FirstOrLast <> 'First'
```